# Why is one of my Windsor Installers being called twice?

Tags: castle-windsor

I have two installers in separate assemblies, one in the assembly that the bootstrap code is, and one in another references assembly.

I'm bootstrapping like such:

```
container = new WindsorContainer()
   .Install(FromAssembly.InThisApplication(), FromAssembly.Named("My.Other.Assembly"));
```

The installer in the second assembly ("My.Other.Assembly") for some reason is being called twice, which is obviously causing problems in trying to register duplicate components.

Any ideas why that might happen?

Answer (score 3):

`FromAssembly.InThisApplication()` will scan the current assembly and all assemblies that have the current assembly name as a prefix (including the dot though).

So, if your app is called either `My` or `My.Other`, then `My.Other.Assembly` will be scanned both as a result of `FromAssembly.InThisApplication()` and as a result of including it explicitly.

Could it be that this is what's messing with you?

Comment: Good thinking.... I thought of that too... sadly no, they have completely different names.